# Currently receiving data from Serial Port, now data will be received from TCP IP port

Tags: java, serial-port, tcp

Currently I am using a Java program to read data from a machine that is connected through a Serial Port. 
The purpose of this machine is to send data at irregular intervals over serial port. 
In Java program I have implemented SerialPortEventListener where I am calling serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) to read data from machine. 
Whenever, machine sends data at irregular intervals, my Java code is able to listen to that event and data is read successfully.

Now client wish to purchase a new machine which will communicate data only over TCP/IP port. 
I have already goggled this and have understood how to read data over TCP/IP port using sockets in Java.

However challenge that comes in my mind is reading data from machine at irregular intervals. 
Like in serial port this is automatically done using serialEvent function as this function is automatically triggered on incoming data, BUT how is this possible in TCP/IP ?

Comment: the approach you need to take is to stream the data over a TCP/IP connection as it arrives on the serial port. You can establish a TCP/IP session before hand, and write new data to the TCP/IP stream as it arrives in your method. Alternatively you could establish the connection stream the data, and immediately close it. Each packet of data received would then open / send and close. It's less efficient this way but either approach will be successful.

Comment: Thankyou for reply, the concern here is that we will receive data in TCP/IP port only. Using Serial port is out of question as new hardware does not support this. Your solution would have worked perfectly fine if, we were still receiving data in Serial port and want to communicate it to TCP/IP port.